# Android Parse.com getting the id of a user

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I'm working in an android app adding the following/follower system, I'm using the lines in the Parse.com, I have a user profile, and when I click on the follow button the app send the both users id (the current user and the other user) in a row. I'm using pointers targeting the _user class.

This is my current code :

```
Intent i = get intent();
String userId =         i.getStringExtra("userid");

ParseObject follow = new     ParseObject("Follow");
  follow.put("from",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

follow.put("to", userId);
             follow.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                 @Override
 public void done(ParseException e) {
                  btn_follow.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_following));
            }
        });

 The btn_follow change the image.     which means the following has been done.     but my Follow class is empty.
```

I have changed my Follow table from :
...|from|to|
To :
...|from|to|

This worked well the both users id were saved, but I need pointers not string so I put from and to to pointers again and deleted the line

```
 follow.put("to", userId);
```

This worked well also but it only saved the current user and not the user I'm trying to follow.
So my problem is with the ID of the user I want to follow.
In the guide they are saying

```
 "ParseUser otheruser = ..."
```

(I don't no what to put in the 3 points to get the other user id)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a ParseObject (or ParseUser) to create a pointer in database. For this you need to create ParseUser without data, just with id like this:

```
follow.put("to", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", userId));
```

Also, you should check the ParseException e in callback to see whats going on.